# How to use GroupBy using TypeORM respository in NestJs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I didn't find any syntax to use GroupBy in query using TypeORM respository.

"addGroupBy" keyword is available via queryBuilder but I'm using TypeORM respository pattern to fetch the data from database.